# How to argue omitted variable problem is alleviated?

Tags: regression, model-selection, econometrics, endogeneity

Is there any ways to argue that the omitted variable problem is alleviated after adding a new variable to the model? Right now I'm basically just saying that adding this new variable significantly improves model fit (based on LR test). What else (such as some specific tests? ) can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [this paper](http://brown.edu/research/projects/oster/sites/brown.edu.research.projects.oster/files/uploads/Unobservable_Selection_and_Coefficient_Stability.pdf) by Emily Oster, where she develops a formal
bounding argument for omitted variable bias under the proportional selection relationship between observables and unobservables. Stata code [here](http://brown.edu/research/projects/oster/sites/brown.edu.research.projects.oster/files/uploads/psacalc_files.zip).

Comment: Interesting paper (+1). I'd appreciate, if you'd answer a couple of clarifying questions, as follows. What "proportional selection" in your answer refers to? Is this a general statistical approach or it is bound by certain assumptions or conditions? Is there a related functionality within `R` ecosystem?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Consider a model
$$ y=\alpha + \beta \cdot x  + \Sigma_{j=1}^{C} \gamma_j \cdot x_j +\Sigma_{k=1}^{U} \eta_k \cdot z_k + \varepsilon = \alpha + \beta \cdot x + C + U + \varepsilon,$$
where $y$ is the outcome, $x$ is the variable of interest, $x_j$ are the controls and $z_k$ are the unobserved variables. The proportionality of selection relationship is defined as
$$\delta = \frac{\frac{Cov(U,t)}{Var(U)}}{\frac{Cov(C,t)}{Var(C)}}.$$ 
Essentially, $\delta$ is the ratio of univariate regression coefficients of $x$ on $U$ and $x$ on $C$.

Comment: A $\delta$ of one
indicates that the observed and unobserved variables have an equally important effect on the coefficient of interest. A
$\delta$ greater than one indicates that the unobserved variables are relatively more important. The other ingredient for the bias is the hypothetical $R^2$ from that regression if you had access to the $z$s. I am not aware of an `R` implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. The subject is much clearer to me now - as I understand it's all about having a metric for assessing the relative importance of observed vs. unobserved factors. But why this distinction? I initially thought that the _omitted variable bias_ term can (and should?) be applied to factors irrespective to their belonging to observed or latent classes, hence my mention of _general approach_.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I am not sure what you mean. Once you make assumptions about $\delta$ and the hypothetical $R^2_{MAX},$ this offers a way to get at the magnitude of the OVB from how the $R^2$ and the coefficients change as you add observed covariates.

Comment: I mean why do we care about omitted variable bias in terms of **unobserved vs. observed** rather than in terms of **any omitted variable** (not explicitly included in a model) with no regard to their belonging to the latent class.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I think I finally understand your question. It is possible there are a set of unobserved controls which do not share covariance properties with the observed controls. This procedure will not deal with that sort of bias at all.

Comment: I appreciate your comments and desire to understand my question, but, frankly, I think we still are talking about different things. Let me try one more time to clarify my question. Imagine that there exist a simple regression model $Y = F(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$, which includes `n` predictors. However, there might be other `m` potentially essential predictors, which are not included (_omitted_) in the model. I'd argue that omitting those `m` variables (irrespective of whether they are observable or not!) introduces _omitted variable bias_.

Comment: In the notation above, the first are the $x$s, the second group are the $z$s. The equation above is the data generating process, not an actual regression.

Comment: Correct, I haven't specified regression model in a traditional way - I just wanted to emphasize two groups of variables ($x$s and $z$s, in your notation). Your most recent comment clarified things for me and now I see that we indeed are talking about the same things. It was the term _unobserved_ that confused me initially, since I'm used to SEM **terminology**, where _unobserved_ is a synonym for _latent_, hence my question. I appreciate you taking the time to clarify things.